# Are "about:config" values in firefox readable from websites

Tags: firefox, http-headers, firefox-developer-tools

Are preferences in the `about:config` section readable from websites?

If so - is there a way to hide the changes that we made?

For example i added a value for `general.useragent.override` in the `about:config` and a website seems to recognize this manual change of the value and blocks this traffic.

Comment: In one of your comments to liakoyras' answer you note that you have an add-on installed. Does that affect whether you're blocked or not? Or generally speaking, did you try to access the page without any add-ons? And what happens if you access the website without changed user agent string? Please edit your answer to add those pieces of info!

Answer (score 2):

The sites can't directly read the settings, but they can see their results. You can see what information gets sent to the websites using the Network tab of the developer tools. If you take a look at the headers, you can see your (changed) user agent.

You are most likely blocked because the site rejects your user agent, not because you changed it on Firefox. You could make a Python script that informs the site that your user agent is `Mozilla/5.0` and the site would accept it.

Comment: I checked the results on the following site: https://meinbrowser.info/

The results are exactly the same for this cases:

Windows 10 - Firefox without edited about:config
// Linux - Firefox with edited about:config (took the useragent from Win 10)

However - the results are the same. 

Somehow this special website recognized that i made a change in the about:config, because on windows the website works fine, in linux it is blocked.

I also have a add-on of this special website activated in the browsers - may this add-on can check for added changes?

Comment: I checked with a random string as a user agent (using your setting) and the website showed the custom user agent.

Comment: Sorry - maybe this was missunderstandable. I just used meinbrowser.info to check the useragent, and youre right - it works fine, the idents are identical (Original FF Browser on Win10 and FF Browser on Linux after editing it with a custom Win10 userstring)  //// However the website i use ( ebesucher.de ) somehow recognises that i made changes inside the about:config because for the original it works fine and for the custom it denies its service. The question is, how can they find out that the useragent was faked.

Comment: Is your custom user agent a believable one?

Comment: Sure! I extracted it from the Win10 Firefox - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"   /// is it possible that the addon from ebesucher.de can check for changes made in the about:config? I can't explain it any other way.

Comment: Add-ons _do_ have access to browser preferences when granted on installation. I tried it with a new Firefox profile and only changed the user agent string to the one you mentioned and could access the website normally. So yes, the add-on _could_ be the reason why you're blocked.

Comment: Its not about the homepage ebesucher itself - it is about its service called a "surfbar" - you can earn money for automatic browsing, while Win10 gives more money than Linux. // After changing the general user agent to a custom - the service denies it function and i dont get behind how the service recognises this manuel change.

Comment: @Natrium2 all of those are very pertinent information that should have been included to the original question. When I answered, I answered in a general way based on the information given, but it seems like there is more to it.